# Use multiple jQuery DataTable functions in same Javascript file with different style and ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to use multiple jQuery DataTable functions in the same Javascript file. I know how to use multiple tables in the same page if the tables have the same style, ajax. However, I need to use multiple tables with different style & ajax. The second table doesn't load completely unless I remove the function for the first table.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id*=Table1]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "dom": 'lBfrtip',
    "order": [
      [1, "desc"]
    ],
    "buttons": [{
        extend: 'print',
      },
      {
        extend: 'excel',
      }, {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        title: function() {
          return "PDF Export";
        },
        orientation: 'landscape',
        pageSize: 'A0',
        titleAttr: 'PDF'
      }
    ],
  });
})
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Table2').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "5%",
        "targets": [0]
      },
      {
        "width": "10%",
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": [7]
      },
      {
        "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
        "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
      },
    ],
    "language": {
      "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "MyMethod.aspx/GetData",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "type": "GET",
      "dataType": "JSON",
      "data": function(d) {
        return d;
      },
      "dataSrc": function(json) {
        json.draw = json.d.draw;
        json.recordsTotal = json.d.recordsTotal;
        json.recordsFiltered = json.d.recordsFiltered;
        json.data = json.d.data;

        var return_data = json;
        return return_data.data;
      }
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "FirstName"
      },
      {
        "data": "LastName"
      },
      {
        "data": "MemberID"
      },
      {
        "data": "UserID"
      },
      {
        "data": "ZipCode"
      },
      {
        "data": "Description"
      },
      {
        "data": "ExpiryDate"
      },
      {
        "data": "Action"
      }
    ],
    "buttons": [
      'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. You have at least one syntax error in the JS you've shown - an extra mismatched `}`. It's easier to spot now that I've formatted your code correctly. Also note that you can join the two document.ready handler in to one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I have corrected the syntax errors and that has fixed part of my problem. The second table loads and there are no errors. However, this line of code in the first table is causing the format of my second table to not display correctly: `.prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first")))` The first tables is a grid view that has it's <thead> section inserted automatically. Do you know of a way to ignore this when loading my second table? FYI, the tables are in two separate pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works:

```
var Table1 = $("[id*=Table1]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("[id*=Table1]").find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
```

Here's the whole script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Table1 = $("[id*=Table1]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("[id*=Table1]").find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "order": [
            [1, "desc"]
        ],
        "buttons": [{
            extend: 'print',
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
        }, {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: function () {
                return "PDF Export";
            },
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'A0',
            titleAttr: 'PDF'
        }
        ],
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Table2').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "width": "5%",
            "targets": [0]
        },
        {
            "width": "10%",
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": [7]
        },
        {
            "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
            "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        },
        ],
        "language": {
            "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader - color'></i></div>"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "MyMethod.aspx/GetData",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataType": "JSON",
            "data": function (d) {
                return d;
            },
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                json.draw = json.d.draw;
                json.recordsTotal = json.d.recordsTotal;
                json.recordsFiltered = json.d.recordsFiltered;
                json.data = json.d.data;

                var return_data = json;
                return return_data.data;
            }
        },
        "columns": [{
            "data": "FirstName"
        },
        {
            "data": "LastName"
        },
        {
            "data": "MemberID"
        },
        {
            "data": "UserID"
        },
        {
            "data": "ZipCode"
        },
        {
            "data": "Description"
        },
        {
            "data": "ExpiryDate"
        },
        {
            "data": "Action"
        }
        ],
        "buttons": [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
        ]
    });
});
```